# Javascript variable from array as the object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a selection box with a possible total of 13 options and I'm trying to dump the contents into an object for easier selection.   I figured I could use `Object.assign()`, but the ID's are not helpful to me on the backend because I'm still unsure of what the ID correlates to.  Ideally I'd like the ID to match the selected value.  How can I go about making the object key values match with the actual values?

The code looks sort of like this

```
function addFeature() {
    var confirm0 = document.getElementById("featureName").value;
    var select1 = document.getElementById("acctlist");
    var selected1 = []
    for (var i = 0; i < select1.length; i++) {
      if (select1.options[i].selected)
        selected1.push(select1.options[i].value);
    }
    var object = Object.assign({}, select1);

    var data = { featureName: confirm0, selectedAccts: object};
```

Comment: Please add the `html code` along with desired output.

Comment: What is `data1`?

Comment: You can use `object[select1.options[i].value] = select1.options[i].value;`

Comment: @Barmar sorry that a typo, I added the correct variable.

Comment: @Barmar maybe I'm not doing it right, but that doesn't seem to resolve the issue.  I get the below error.

```addfeature.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'foo' of undefined
    at addFeature (addfeature.js:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (om_addfeature.html:151)
addFeature @ addfeature.js:13
onclick @ om_addfeature.html:151```

Comment: Did you create the object before trying to set its property? `var object = {};`

Comment: `select1` is the DOM element, I don't think you want to use that in `Object.assign()`.

Comment: Ah that was it @Barmar.  Thanks!